# How to open executable with python

Tags: python, python-2.x

Is there a way to open an exe file and save it in a variable?

For example:

```
f = open("text.exe", 'rb')
exe = f.read( )
execute(exe)
```

Comment: You can use `os.system` or `subprocess` to run commands

Comment: I need to do it without terminal commands

Comment: All *.exe files are by their very nature terminal commands. You type foo.exe and the file runs. Are you saying this is some kind of project where you are not allowed to execute the file on the shell itself?

Comment: Yes, i am trying to develop an exe encrypter, and i need to execute the file in this way

Comment: What is an exe encrypter, and what does it have to do with executing the exe?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135809/encryption-for-executable